# Collision detection for a simple 3D game in C++ and OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, 3d, collision-detection

I am attempting to create a simple 3D game using C++ and OpenGL, I am working on Windows in Qt Creator.

So far I have a fish which can be controlled around the screen and a sphere which will act as the food to collect. I am trying to include collision detection so that when the fish hits the food, the food will move to another position. I have a bounding box around the fish and a collision function (the fish can only move in the X and Y direction):

```
void Window::BBoxCollision()
{
  float ext[6];
  ext[0]=ext[1]=(m_bbox->height());
  ext[2]=ext[3]=(m_bbox->width());
  ext[4]=ext[5]=(m_bbox->depth());

    GLfloat collisionLimitX;
    GLfloat collisionLimitY;

    {
      collisionLimitX=currentX+ext[2]+foodRadius;
      collisionLimitY=currentY+ext[0]+foodRadius;

      if(collisionLimitX <= 6 && collisionLimitY <= 6)
      {
        removeFood();
      }
    }
}
```

My issue is that the `currentX` and `currentY` variables are defined in my `Fish.h` class because that is where the function to move the fish is which means I cannot access these values in my `Window.h` class.
This is my move function in my fish cpp:

```
void Fishy::move(float _x, float _y)
{
    currentX=m_pos.m_x;
    currentY=m_pos.m_y;
    m_pos.m_x+=_x;
    m_pos.m_y+=_y;
    if(m_pos.m_x<=-s_xExtents || m_pos.m_x>=s_xExtents)
    {
        m_pos.m_x=currentX;
    }


    if(m_pos.m_y<=-s_yExtents || m_pos.m_y>=s_yExtents)
    {
        m_pos.m_y=currentY;
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can get these values? Or another way I should be going about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One way is to put a collision detector inside the fish class. Your window class can call each fish instance and pass in the food co-ordinates. The fish can then report when it finds food.

Comment: I believe the most common way is to keep all of your game objects in an array, which you would iterate and check for collisions from your windows class.  Your Fish class shouldn't need a lot of logic.  You would need to repeat a lot of code as you add more and more different types of objects to your game.